# get 1 email address from multiple delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column email with multiple delimiters like space ,/ , .

email

```
/john@thundergroup.com.mi/chris@cup.com.ey
r.Info@bc.com / rudi.an@yy.com
Dal@pema.com/Al@ama.com
/randi@mv.com
zul@sd.com/sat@sd.com/ faze@sd.com
```

My query:

```
select email,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', email) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(email, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', email)) ELSE 
email END as Emailnew
FROM table
```

my output:

```
/john@thundergroup.com.mi/chris@cup.com.ey
r.Info@bc.com
Dal@pema.com/Al@ama.com
/randi@mv.com
zul@sd.com/sat@sd.com/ faze@sd.com
```

Please suggest changes so that in a single query I'm able to extract email

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Why do some rows start with a `/` and others not? Does that denote that the first email address is blank? Does `' / '` (note the white space of either side) mean that there are 3 blank email addresses? You state that `.` can also be a delimiter. `.` is used in email addresses, so how do you tell apart that the `.` is a delimiter or part of the email address?

Comment: I just delete my answer because of those details (especially the `.` as delimiter) @Larnu because I didn't read the Q carefully. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first email always, you can try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2633cf5e0642c2398548f4e7a74530b)

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('/',email,2) = 0 THEN REPLACE(email,'/','')
    ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTRING(email,0,CHARINDEX('/',email,2)),'/','')
END
FROM your_table
```

Output will be-

```
john@thundergroup.com.mi
r.Info@bc.com 
Dal@pema.com
randi@mv.com
zul@sd.com
```

Answer (score 0):

On modern SQL Servers try something like:

```sql
-- Setup...
create table dbo.Foo (
  FooID int not null identity primary key,
  Email nvarchar(100)
);

insert dbo.Foo (Email) values
  ('/john@thundergroup.com.mi/chris@cup.com.ey'),
  ('r.Info@bc.com / rudi.an@yy.com'),
  ('Dal@pema.com/Al@ama.com'),
  ('/randi@mv.com'),
  ('zul@sd.com/sat@sd.com/ faze@sd.com');
go

-- Demo...
select FooID, [Email]=value
from dbo.Foo
outer apply (
  select top 1 value
  from string_split(translate(Email, ' /', ';;'), ';')
  where nullif(value, '') is not null
) Splitzville;
```

Which yields:

```
FooID  Email
1      john@thundergroup.com.mi
2      r.Info@bc.com
3      Dal@pema.com
4      randi@mv.com
5      zul@sd.com
```

Requirements:

- SQL Server 2016 and later for [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).
- SQL Server 2017 and later for [translate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first email only, use `patindex()`:

```
select email,
       left(email, patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]%', email + ' ') - 1) as Emailnew
from table;
```

The pattern (`a-zA-Z0-9@.`) are valid email characters.  You may have additional ones that you care about.

Unfortunately, I notice that some of your lists start with delimiter characters.  In my opinion, the above works correctly by returning an empty value.  That said, your desired results are to get the second value in that case.

So, you have to start the search at the first valid email character:

```
select t.email,
       left(v.email1, patindex('%[^-_a-zA-Z0-9@.]%', v.email1 + ' ') - 1) as Emailnew
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.email, 1, patindex('%[-_a-zA-Z0-9@.]%', t.email) - 1, ''))) v(email1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b12f4a8c59904cdc60449996b9557825) is a db<>fiddle.